# How to overlay an image over another image?

Tags: html, css, image

I want one image above the other. How can I do it?

[image: example]
http://twitpic.com/2cnpku

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! You don't need to whine for help. I've edited it away because helpful users would otherwise move along. Just ask the question the smart way. You're already at the right place to get help :)

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevants parts of code into your question. It will make it easier for people to help you and also future users to see your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image you want on top to have a higher z-index. Right now, it has a lower z-index.

Comment: the problem is the images are not showing but everything is right name and address

Answer (score 4):

from the code you posted, it appears you are passing an `img` element into another `src` attribute of another `img` element. Is there a reason you are doing this?

```
<style type="text/css">
  .imgA1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:2;
    width:1300px;
    height:283px;
  }
  .imgB1 {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     z-index:1;
     width:1300px;
     height:1000px;
  }
</style>
<img class="imgA1" src="images/home_nav.png" alt="home_nav" />
<img class="imgB1" src="images/paperbackground.png" alt="Background" />
```

A similar code mockup can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/gBPBd/3/ with my images to prove the concept and it is funcitoning in chrome, ie8.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel But The Home Nav image is still behind the paper background image. @Gabriel

Comment: <style type="text/css">
  // if imgA1 is intended to be on top set a higher z-index
  .imgA1 {position:absolute;
          top:0px;
          left:0px;
          z-index:3;
          width:1300px,
          height:283px;}
  .imgB1 {position:absolute;
          top:0px;
          left:0px;
          z-index:1;
          width:1300px,
          height:1000px;}
</style>

----------------------------------
.imga1 is staying behind??

Comment: I worked on it a bit more, looks like my comment was breaking the selector. I have modified it. You can also see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/gBPBd/3/ though I have used my own images so you can see the result.

Comment: Working Now Thanks Everybody!